# Video upload to Instagram Business Account always returns "Media ID is not available" error message

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I need to publish either a photo or video to an authenticated Instagram Business Account.

I have gotten the access token to the Instagram Business Account and now I wish to upload a video to that account but I keep getting back this error message

> Media ID is not available

I followed the instructions to upload either a video or photo from the docs here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing/

Please note that the below code works perfectly well at uploading Photos but always fails when it's video.

Here is my code after following their documentation:

```
let mediaContainerUrl = `https://graph.facebook.com/${igUserId}/media`;
let containerParams = new URLSearchParams();
if (isPhoto) {
    containerParams.append('image_url', mediaUrl);
} else {
    containerParams.append('video_url', mediaUrl);
    containerParams.append('media_type', 'VIDEO');
}
containerParams.append('caption', caption);
containerParams.append('access_token', accessToken);
try {
    let mediaContainerResponse = await axios.post(mediaContainerUrl, containerParams);
    let { id } = mediaContainerResponse.data;

    // id above is supposed to be the creation_id needed for the next step below:

    // I can confirm that the id for the created media container was actually returned. 
    // So, it's weird for me to keep getting the Media ID not available error message.

    let mediaPublishResponse = await axios.post(`https://graph.facebook.com/${igUserId}/media_publish?creation_id=${id}&access_token=${access_token}`);
    let mediaPublishResponseData = mediaPublishResponse.data;
    let publishedMediaId = mediaPublishResponseData.id;
    console.log(`File uploaded to Instagram!`);

} catch (e) {
    console.log(`Instagram file upload failed miserably`);
    console.log(e);
}
```

Please note that `mediaUrl` above is coming from a remote url e.g `https://somewhere.com/video.mp4`

Once again, uploading a Photo with the above code is **working perfectly** but never works when it's video. I keep getting the following full error message:

> OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "Media ID is not available

After careful observation I noticed that indeed the `creation_id` was generated for the video, so quite frankly, it's weird that I am still getting the above error message.

Please, what could I be doing wrong?

I'm thankful to any suggestions in resolving this.

Comment: We've had a recent bug report around this which turned out to be a transient issue https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/573962873949266/  If you continue to experience this please open a new bug report at https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs

Answer (score 3):

So, here is what the problem is. When you upload a video to the /media endpoint, the video takes some time to be processed, and the video will not be available for publishing during this time, hence the reason the /media_publish endpoint is returning "Media Id not available". The solution to this would be to check for the container's publishing status: `GET: /{ig-container-id}?fields=status_code`. Only when the status_code is "FINISHED" is the container available for publishing. Check the link below for more details

[IG content publish troubleshooting](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing/#troubleshooting)

Comment: Right answer, direct to the spot

Answer (score 1):

@aib is correct.

You need to check the status of the media container before calling publish. Meta's [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing/#troubleshooting) states:

> If you are able to create a container for a video but the POST
> /{ig-user-id}/media_publish endpoint does not return the published
> media ID, you can get the container's publishing status by querying
> the GET /{ig-container-id}?fields=status_code endpoint.

It takes some time, depending on the size of the video you are uploading, for the container to be ready for publish. For a 1Mb video, it took me ~10 seconds for the media container to be available. I check for the `GET /{ig-container-id}?fields=status_code` endpoint to return `FINISHED` and only then I can finally use the [media_publish](https://developers.facebook.com/micro_site/url/?click_from_context_menu=true&country=IN&destination=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Finstagram-api%2Freference%2Fig-user%2Fmedia_publish%23creating&event_type=click&last_nav_impression_id=05xNJvbVbt634scXf&max_percent_page_viewed=99&max_viewport_height_px=979&max_viewport_width_px=1920&orig_http_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Finstagram-api%2Fguides%2Fcontent-publishing%2F&orig_request_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fajax%2Fdocs%2Fnav%2F%3Fpath1%3Dinstagram-api%26path2%3Dguides%26path3%3Dcontent-publishing&region=apac&scrolled=true&session_id=1Mv33U2UWTs6dDMYu&site=developers) endpoint with the creationId.

```
async function checkIfMediaContainerReady(containerReady) {
  if (!containerReady) {
    console.log('waiting for ig media container to be ready...');
    await sleep(5000);
    let res = await Request(mediaContainerStatusCheckUrl, {method: "GET", headers: headers});
    let statusResponseJson = await JSON.parse(res);
    await checkIfMediaContainerReady(statusResponseJson.status_code === 'FINISHED');
  }
}

const res = await Request(mediaContainerStatusCheckUrl, {method: "GET", headers: headers});
const statusResponseJson = await JSON.parse(res);
await checkIfMediaContainerReady(statusResponseJson.status_code === 'FINISHED');

console.log("ig media container is ready");
```