400 Bad Request Error with Axios POST Call to Threads API, Works in Postman
I'm encountering an issue with an Axios POST request to the Threads API in my Node.js application. The request works perfectly in Postman but fails with a 400 Bad Request error when trying to post video content through the script. Below are the details of my implementation.

module.exports = async (title, url) => {
  try {
    // create media container
    console.log(
      "video_url",
      url,
      "text:",
      title,
      "access_token",
      process.env.THREADS_ACCESS_TOKEN
    );
    const mediaContainer = await axios.post(
      "https://graph.threads.net/v1.0/8063816050370756/threads",
      {
        media_type: "VIDEO",
        video_url: url,
        text: title,
        access_token: process.env.THREADS_ACCESS_TOKEN, // change token in 60 days from august 25 2024
      }
    );
    const mediaID = mediaContainer.data.id;
    console.log("***** MEDIA ID *****", mediaID);
    // post -> THE FOLLOWING CALL RETURN 400 BAD REQUEST
    const postId = await axios.post(
      "https://graph.threads.net/v1.0/8063816050370756/threads_publish",
      {
        creation_id: mediaID,
        access_token: process.env.THREADS_ACCESS_TOKEN,
      }
    );
    console.log(postId);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error in uploading to Threads...moving on", err.message);
  }
};


Details:
The first POST request to https://graph.threads.net/v1.0/8063816050370756/threads works correctly and returns a mediaID.
The second POST request to https://graph.threads.net/v1.0/8063816050370756/threads_publish fails with a 400 Bad Request.
Posting text using the same endpoint works perfectly.
Things I've Tried:

Verified that the access_token and mediaID are correct.
Ensured that the environment variable for THREADS_ACCESS_TOKEN is correctly set and accessible.


Solved. When it comes to video, the media container takes a while to be generated so I was basically trying to post it right after obtaining the media container id. I needed to implement a check on the status code.
Here's the full code:

module.exports = async (title, url) => {
  try {
    // create media container
    console.log(
      "video_url",
      url,
      "text:",
      title,
      "access_token",
      process.env.THREADS_ACCESS_TOKEN
    );
    const mediaContainer = await axios.post(
      "https://graph.threads.net/v1.0/8063816050370756/threads",
      {
        media_type: "VIDEO",
        video_url: url,
        redirect_uri: "https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback",
        text: title,
        access_token: process.env.THREADS_ACCESS_TOKEN, // change token in 60 days from august 25 2024
      }
    );
    const mediaID = mediaContainer.data.id;
    console.log("***** MEDIA ID *****", mediaID);

    // Step 2: Check the status of the media container
    let status = "IN_PROGRESS";
    while (status !== "FINISHED") {
      console.log("Checking status for mediaID:", mediaID);
      const statusCheck = await axios.get(
        `https://graph.threads.net/v1.0/${mediaID}?fields=status&access_token=${process.env.THREADS_ACCESS_TOKEN}`
      );
      status = statusCheck.data.status;
      console.log("Current status:", status);

      if (status !== "FINISHED") {
        // Wait for a few seconds before checking again
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000)); // 5-second delay
      }
    }

    // post
    const postId = await axios.post(
      "https://graph.threads.net/v1.0/8063816050370756/threads_publish",
      {
        creation_id: mediaID,
        redirect_uri: "https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback",
        access_token: process.env.THREADS_ACCESS_TOKEN,
      }
    );
    console.log(postId);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.response) {
      console.log("Error in uploading to Threads...");
      console.log("Status:", err.response.status);
      console.log("Headers:", err.response.headers);
      console.log("Data:", err.response.data);
    } else {
      console.log("Unknown error in uploading to Threads...", err.message);
    }
  }
};

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71242414/13556684

Thanks for your sharing. This helped me.
